# preserve whitespace from find -printf output

Tags: bash, find, printf

I'm reading the file list with fond and outputting it with -printf where I'm basically creating a string separated by newline chars. When I try to loop through this, filenames with whitespace characters in them render as new entry.

How would I read this while preserving the whitespace in filenames?

```
loop() {
    files=$(find "${base}" -name "*" -printf "%TD%TT|%p\n")

    for string in $files
    do 
        stamp=${string%|*}
        file=${string#*|}

        echo "$stamp - $file"
    done
}
```

Comment: why not feed your `find` directly into a `while` loop. Search here for `[bash] find while printf0 xargs`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to shellter's comment, the While loop allowed me to separate the lines into variables:

```
loop() {
    while read string
    do
        stamp=${string%|*}
        file=${string#*|}

        files_new[$file]=$stamp
    done < <(find "${base}" -name "*" -printf "%TD%TT|%p\n")
}
```

Comment: Try `while IFS=\| read -r file stamp; do files_new[$file]=$stamp;done < <(find "$base" -name \* -printf "%TD%TT|%p\n")`

Comment: Don't mind me from asking, but what would be the benefit from this?

Comment: Not much, just saving `stamp=${string%|*}` and `file=${string#*|}` at the beggining of `for`'s loop body. It is also more readable.

Comment: ...I fail to understand the meaning of `"*"` as the argument to `-name`. It seems to be redundant. :-)

Comment: Seems like you're right, still returns my array. Wasn't sure if it would print just directories or what not.

Comment: Ok, cool. To be sure see `find`'s `-type` option and its arguments. For example, you can choose to output directories only by passing the *d* argument, output files only by passing *f* and more.